# extra numbers showing up on my axes when i do multiple subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

hi folks first python question here!

so big picture, i have a panel with 4 dataframes in it. i wanted a function that just plots the panel in 4 subplots, with a tiny bit of data processing on it..

When i try to set up subplots i get weird numbers on both axes of my subplots 2 and higher. I dont know where they come from, plain and simple, and nobody seems to have had the same problem. any advice friends?

```
def plotAlexaPanel(getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput, selection = 'Aggregate', defaultlookback = -200):
    '''nicely formatted plots from getWebsiteListStatistics'''
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2) #, sharex=True)
    fig.tight_layout()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plotAlexaPanelSubPlot(ax1, "viewsPerU",getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput, selection, defaultlookback)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
    plotAlexaPanelSubPlot(ax2, "viewsPerM",getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput, selection, defaultlookback)
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
    plotAlexaPanelSubPlot(ax3, "reachPerM",getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput, selection, defaultlookback)
    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)
    plotAlexaPanelSubPlot(ax4, "pageRank",getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput, selection, defaultlookback)
    #plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
    suptitle(selection, fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    fig.set_size_inches(18.5,10.5)
    return

def plotAlexaPanelSubPlot(subplotaxis, subplotmetric,getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput, selection = 'Aggregate', defaultlookback = -200):
    if selection == 'Aggregate':
        if subplotmetric == 'pageRank':
            subplotmetric2 = 'minRank'
        elif subplotmetric == 'viewsPerU':
            subplotmetric2 = 'aggregateViewsU'
        elif subplotmetric == 'viewsPerM':
            subplotmetric2 = 'aggregateViews'
        elif subplotmetric == 'reachPerM':
            subplotmetric2 = 'aggregateReach'
        else:
            subplotmetric2 = subplotmetric
        getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput['aggregate'][subplotmetric2][defaultlookback:].plot(legend=False,ax=subplotaxis)
        yoygrowth(getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput['aggregate'][subplotmetric2])[defaultlookback:].plot(legend=False,ax=subplotaxis, secondary_y=True)
    else:
        getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput['rawOutput'][subplotmetric][selection][defaultlookback:].plot(legend=False,ax=subplotaxis)
        yoygrowth(getWebsiteListStatisticsOutput['rawOutput'][subplotmetric][selection])[defaultlookback:].plot(legend=False,ax=subplotaxis, secondary_y=True)
    subplotaxis.set_ylabel(subplotmetric +  ' (Blue)')
    subplotaxis.right_ax.set_ylabel('YoY% (Green)')
    subplotaxis.set_xlabel('')
    return
```

[image: i put red arrows to highlight weird extra numbers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `plt.subplots(2,2)` call adds four AxesSubplot objects to the figure and the `fig.add_subplot()` calls each add one more*.  You're plotting data to this second set of axes, which is why the rogue tick labels span zero to one. That's the default graph when you don't plot any data to an axes instance.

The simplest way to fix this is to replace

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
```

with

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

which will stop adding the unused axes.

* Well, sort of.  Behind the scenes the `fig.add_subplot()` call checks whether the figure already has a subplot with this call signature and, if it does, returns it rather than creating a new subplot.  This is what happens for your first subplot, but the next three have slightly different call signatures, probably related to `sharex`/`sharey` arguments, so for them new subplots are created.

Comment: It would be far better to do `fig, [[ax1, ax2], [ax3, ax4]] = plt.subplots(2, 2)`.

Comment: thanks Deditos! im evidently copying and pasting stuff without really understanding what is going on behind the scenes :) learning pains.